# SQL SERVER - Violation of UNIQUE KEY Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert distinct values into a table using INSERT SELECT.
This is my Query

```
INSERT INTO oltp.Region(Region_Name,Country_Id)
(SELECT DISTINCT region,country_id FROM csv.Neighbourhoods, oltp.Country)
```

These are the tables

oltp.Country

[image]

csv.Neighbourhoods

[image]

I want to have a table which shows the Region name and the Country FK in which they come from.

These are the table creations

```
CREATE TABLE oltp.Country
(Country_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Country_Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE)

CREATE TABLE oltp.Region
(Region_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Region_Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Country_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES oltp.Country(Country_Id))
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. If you ran your query (`SELECT DISTINCT region,country_id FROM csv.Neighbourhoods, oltp.Country`) you'd very quickly see the problem. Do you *really* mean to have a `CROSS JOIN` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `JOIN`!

```
INSERT INTO oltp.Region (Region_Name,Country_Id)
    SELECT DISTINCT n.region, c.country_id
    FROM csv.Neighbourhoods n JOIN
         oltp.Country c
         ON n.country = c.country_name;
```

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Also, you should be storing the country id in the `Neighbourhoods` table, not the name.